# How to stop or remove a file in windows startup folder under 10 seconds

Tags: windows-7, boot, shutdown

I had an app call shutdown.exe that can shut down my computers.

It just an app that will shut down my computer with the specific time, i set to 10 seconds, it just very fine until yesterday, i accidently put it in my windows startup folder and turn off my computers.

So now everytime i startup my computer, that app will shut down my computer in 10 seconds, it make my computer unusable, so can anyone help?

I using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume booting up in Safe Mode could let you find the program without starting up any startup apps.

- Boot into WinRE using your system boot key, or by holding Shift and clicking restart on the log-in screen.
- Boot into Safe Mode by following the WinRE menu through advanced options.
- Once inside Safe Mode, find the file and neutralize it. Take it out of the Startup folder, or just delete it altogether.

In the case that it doesn't, make some Live Media (USB, DVD) and click Repair Installation. Use the command prompt to navigate to where your file is using `cd (filepath)`, and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

- Boot Windows 7 in "Safe Mode". Hold F8 during boot. [Detailed instructions here.](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-start-windows-7-in-safe-mode-2624540)
- Move the program out of the Startup folder.